# Ubuntu 16, Java -jar: Could not find or load main class pattypan.Main

Tags: 16.04, java, github, jar

Just spend hours searching and I found a lot of questions related to this, but this is more simple. All the other questions I found are  developers asking what to do when they get this error.

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class pattypan.Main"
```

I downloaded an application, specific this one [pattypan.jar](https://github.com/yarl/pattypan) 
So I open the terminal, and I type `java -jar pattypan.jar`. 
I get the error "Could not find or load main class pattypan.Main.

Oh yeah I also tried to follow the "Build and run" instructions on the github, but I never got passed the 4th command simply because that "store" directory it tried to make, was not created.with the "ant package-for-store" command.

And that's it, does anyone have an idea? 
I am using Ubuntu 16, I have java installed runtime 7 and 8 I tried installing openjfx all things based on solutions I found. It works on Mac Os x and on windows, so the application is not broken.
I am not a developer, just a user. If there is anything else of system information you would need, tell me how to get it and I'll supply it.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed the packages `openjdk-8-jdk` and `openjfx`. If not, try installing these and running the jar again.

Comment: Running `javac -version` gives me `javac 9-internal` as output. I installed openjdk-8-jdk and openjfx like I mentioned, still gives me the same error. `  Could not find or load main class pattypan.Main`

Comment: Have you used java alternatives to configure the system to use that version?

Comment: I have no idea what that means, so I'm going to make a guess answer, no I only installed java.

Comment: Try this command `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar pattypan.jar`. Does that work?

Comment: YES! it works! How!? if you please, can you explain?

Comment: The project github page states that the application requires JDK-8. Applications do not always work with newer versions of JDK. The command that works forces the use of JDK-8 by using the absolute filename for Java. Without using the absolute filename, the system is using JDK-9 (which is obviously not compatible) and this is why you're seeing an error in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the help this is going to come in handy in the future.